# What does refering to someone as a "garden shed" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, complements

http://youtu.be/a9GgU3hzGGw?t=1m54s
In the following video, a talk host watches an acting performance, and refers to the actor as a "garden shed". 
I've never heard that expression before.  I am also not British.

I imagine it means someone who can do anything, though I can't find a source for it anywhere on the Internet.  Am I correct in this assumption?  Is this a commonly used expression in the United Kingdom?

Comment: Start watching the video at 1:40. The reference follows a cut at about 1:53, and [to me at least, and I am British] it's not clear exactly what the presenter is referring to. *Garden shed* is Cockney rhyming slang for *red* but I don't **think** that's relevant.

Comment: As @Andrew says, it’s right after a cut. Presumably during that cut, a preview of the new Dr. Who thing that they’re talking about was played (and deleted from the YouTube version for copyright reasons), and in that preview, something appeared that the presenter is calling a garden shed. There really is no way to tell whether it’s a person or a thing he’s referring to, but it sounds more likely to be the latter to me—perhaps the Doctor has acquired a lavish villa now, and that is what’s sarcastically being called a garden shed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a reference to the cut, which featured the Doctor (played by John Hurt) in what could loosely be described as a garden shed.

No meaning beyond that, I'm afraid!

Comment: As evidence, here's an image from inside the shed from the episode that the host is likely referring to: http://www.nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/DOCTOR-WHO-50TH-ANNIVERSARY_THE-DAY-OF-THE-DOCTOR_64.jpg

Comment: @apsillers Of course. Couldn't say it was much of a garden, though.

Answer (score 0):

According to one site 'garden shed' is rhyming slang for a 'locked thread', which would seem to fit with the way it is used in the video. Was the speaker complaining sarcastically that they had cut the trailer at the interesting point?